# iOS5 jQuery.scroll() event not triggered with overflow: scroll

Tags: jquery, ios5

When I have a `div` in a webpage with the css property `overflow: scroll` in iOS5 I am able to scroll through the div by moving my finger over the screen. This movement does not trigger the `$.scroll()` event of jQuery while in the browser it does. I am wondering if anyone knows a workaround so the scroll event is triggered as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the $.scroll function will be triggered on the overflow: scroll div. The problem was the script with the $.scroll function was triggered before the div existed.